# Get local variable returned to another method in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am working on a school lab, and I am having a hell of a time with something that should be fairly basic.  I have a series of buttons and 2 text-boxes.  I have 1 method that all buttons go through and get passed to a new method to determine the instructions needed.

From the new method it calculates and returns the value.

Code looks like this, only using 1 button and its associated if statement in the other method.

```
public void PassControlDataOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string toCall = "";
        string szLeft = box_L_Input.Text;
        string szRight = box_R_Input.Text;

        decimal dLeft = Convert.ToDecimal(szLeft);
        decimal dRight = Convert.ToDecimal(szRight);

        if (sender.ToString() == "+")
        {
            toCall = "ADD";
        }
       
        decimal dAnswer = MathCalc(dLeft, dRight, toCall);
        
        string szAnswer = dAnswer.ToString();
        string szEquation = $"{szLeft}{" "}{((Control)sender).Text}{" "}{szRight}{" = "}{szAnswer}";
        lbl_Output.Text = szEquation;
    }

public decimal MathCalc(decimal dL, decimal dR, string toCall)
    {
        decimal dA = 0.0m;
        if (toCall == "ADD")
        {
            dA = dL + dR;
        }
        return dA;
    }
```

Every time I run this, the output I get is from the line decimal dA = 0.0m;
I need it to be the return value but for the life of me I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Yeah I edited it to include the call.  It wasn't a syntax error, that was a copy/paste error on my part lol

Comment: I do not think … `sender.ToString() == "+"` … is working as you expect. Unless you have some modified `Button` control, `sender.ToString()` is going to return something like… _”System.Windows.Forms.Button, Text: button1”_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you step through this code in a debugger, you will see that the `if (sender.ToString() == "+")` line is stepped over.

Further more, you can run `sender.ToString()` in the debugger's Immediate Window and see that it returns `System.Windows.Forms.Button, Text: +` (assuming your sender is a normal button with the text `+`.

In other words, this if check has no hope of ever doing what you want.  Since you know the `sender` will be a Button, you can cast it to a Button class and get the `Text` value out to see if it's indeed the `+` button:

```csharp
            if (((Button)sender).Text == "+")
            {
                toCall = "ADD";
            }
```

Comment: Good god thank you.  I've been at this for so long.  I have coded and recoded this crap sooo many times, changing public and private and data types and adding ref and removing ref.  THANK YOU!